# Usage of 'had + verb'

Tags: have

I saw this sentence in an English article.

> It’s time we had a serious rethink about “learning.”

There are some questions about this sentence.

1. Why the word 'had' has past tense in this sentence
2. What does 'had' mean in this sentence. It seems like 'had + verb' has some special meaning.

and If I made some mistakes in this question. Please let me know. I'm all ears.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cambridge Dictionary reads:

We can use the expression it’s time + subject + past verb form to refer to the present moment:

> **Correct:** Gosh! It’s almost midnight. It’s time we *went* home.
>
> **Not:** It’s time we go home.

However, "It’s time" with a verb in the to-infinitive form can refer to the speaker and the listener together:

> Come on. It’s time to start packing. We have to leave in two hours.
>   (or It’s time we started packing.)

Comment: Thank you. You are such a genius. I want to be like you someday.